# Use of 0.0.0.0 as Default Gateway?

Tags: linux, routing, gateway

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

Why 0.0.0.0 here is used as a gateway? What does 0.0.0.0 signify as a Gateway?

As per my understanding, 0.0.0.0 is used as the default route when the packet does not match with any other entry in the routing table, (first entry in the table). The other two entries use 0.0.0.0 as the Gateway. This is a bit confusing?

Comment: can someone please tell me why this question is getting negative votes?

Comment: Possibly because this type of information is easily found elsewhere and because it is off-topic as per http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Comment: My question is about network routing, so why it is off topic?

Comment: I find it too bad that novice questions get closed like this. For instance, I am a senior web developer with some networking knowledge, but I had a similar question. Ladadadada's answerbelow gave me the explanation I needed. By chance, he was quick enough to write his answer before the topic was closed. Maybe people should give themselves a rating when they register to a stack exchage site (novice, intermediate, advanced). That way users of the site, could filter what they want to see (e.g. all questions or only advanced users questions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0.0.0.0` has a different meaning depending on which column it is in.

The combination of `Destination` and `Genmask` creates an IP address range.  In CIDR notation, yours are:

```
0.0.0.0/0
169.254.0.0/16
192.168.1.0/24
```

When an IP packet is sent, the destination is matched to these ranges and the gateway is chosen accordingly.  The range `0.0.0.0/0` matches all IPv4 addresses.  This row is your *default* gateway and will be used if no other range matches.  Your default gateway is `192.168.1.1`.

For packets where the destination is local, no gateway is necessary and the packet is sent to the switch to be sent directly to the correct machine.  (The details of hubs vs. switches are not important here.  The important part is that no gateway is necessary for local packets.)

In the `Gateway` column in this output, `0.0.0.0` indicates that there is no gateway and the packet should be sent locally.

---

There's a simple [introduction to Linux routing here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understand-the-basics-of-linux-routing/) and a far more [in-depth look at Linux routing here](http://linux-ip.net/html/ch-routing.html).